# gzip: stdin: not in gzip format when gunzip is used with pipe

Tags: command-line

I uncompress file in the following way:

> gunzip file.gz

But when I do it with pipe, it returns the error.

> echo file.gz | gunzip
>   gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

What's the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `echo file.gz` just echoes a string "file.gz". Basically the difference between the commands is:

What you want:

`gunzip /path/to/directory/file.gz`

What you're giving it with the echo:

`gunzip "file.gz"`

However, even this isn't entirely correct. The true difference is that instead of a reference to the **file** `file.gz` you're sending in only the **string** "file.gz"

I guess the real question here is why are you trying to pipe to `gunzip` instead of just using it as `gunzip file.gz`?

EDIT: It seems that doing `echo file.gz | xargs gunzip` does the trick, as well.

Comment: I see. I test with command "echo file.gz | xarg gunzip", it works! This is part of a shell script. The file name will be composed before this gunzip command.

Comment: ok, cool. I hadn't thought to use `xargs`