# 'gzip: file.log.gz: not in gzip format' error

Tags: command-line, gzip

I have a `.gz` folder and I tried to unzip it using terminal by the following commands, but gave error.

```
gunzip access-2.log.gz  
gzip -d access-2.log.gz
```

[image: gunzip]
[image: gzip]

Then I followed the error in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562763/gzip-stdin-not-in-gzip-format-when-gunzip-is-used-with-pipe)
After that I gave the command in terminal

```
gunzip Desktop/project/data/access-2.log.gz
```

similar error.[image: path]

Why I'm getting this issue?
What is the solution to unzip the `name.log.gz` folder?

Comment: Run `file access-2.log.gz`, it will tell you the compression type.

Comment: command 'file access-2.log.gz' gave : access-2.log.gz: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines

Comment: can it be unzippable?

Comment: Try `head access-2.log.gz`. Does it show the start of the log file?

Comment: If the command proposed by Olathe doesn't show the start of the file please explain exactly how you compressed the *file*. `gzip` can compress only a single *file* at the time, it can't compress a *folder* or *multiple files*.

Comment: `head access-2.log.gz` command gave me this output and some other similar lines below 

 `1335451033 188 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/404 327 GET http://keithalexander.co.uk/robots.txt - NONE/- text/html`

Comment: That is the start of the log. Your file is not compressed, so it just has the wrong extension. `mv access-2.log.gz access-2.log` and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its simple, I had the similar problem while ago, what I did was just rename the file.
that is to remove the `.gz` from the file name. Then it looks like `access.log`. So you can view it using any editor you have